# Not sure why a certain sequence of functions shows that the unit ball is not compact in $C([0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

I read [here](https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/function-spaces-and-compactness/) that the unit ball is not compact in $C([0,1])$ with the sup norm, because the sequence of functions implied by the image below do not have a convergent subsequence. But surely this sequence of functions converges to $f(x)=1$ which is in $C([0,1])$, and hence we do have a convergent subsequence, i.e. the subsequence is the sequence itself. Am I mistaken?

[image]

Comment: How about $x=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence $f_n$ certainly converges pointwise, but that does not imply convergence in the space $C([0,1])$.  For functions $\phi_n\in C([0,1])$ to 
converge to a function $\phi\in C([0,1])$, one must have
$$
\|\phi-\phi_n\|_{C([0,1])} = \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |\phi(x)-\phi_n(x)| \to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$.  However for the functions $f_n$ as you have them,
$$
\|f-f_n\|_{C([0,1])} \geq |f(0)-f_n(0)| = 1.
$$
This clearly doesn't converge to zero, so the $f_n$ do not converge in $C([0,1])$.

We can even see that there can be no convergent subsequence among the $f_n$ as follows.  Let $n>0$.  Then for any $m>2n$,
$$
\|f_n-f_m\|_{C([0,1])} \geq \left|f_n\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) - f_m\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)\right| 
= \frac{1}{2}.
$$
This implies that no subsequence can be Cauchy.

Comment: Great, I get it now! One last thing if you have a minute..I get that the unit ball in $C([0,1])$ is not compact now, but why is it still closed?

Comment: @Riggs Since the norm is continuous, $\overline{B}(0,1) = {\|\cdot\|_\infty}^{-1}\big([0,1]\big)$ is closed as a preimage of a closed set by a continuous function.